# javascript - filtering a table by time range

Tags: javascript, html

So I have index file that contains a flight schedule table. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Picture]

The table also allows for sorting by airline and departure time, and a filter by airline name. My question is how do I add filtering by time range? I'd like to filter the flight by departure time from 8 AM to 2 PM, but I have no idea what to do.

Here is the code for the js containing the data, rendertable, and filter function.

airportflight.js

```
let flight_data = [{
    "airlines": "GA",
    "departure_airport": "CGK",
    "departure_time": "2021-08-17T08:20",
    "arival_airport": "SIN",
    "arival_time": "2021-08-17T10:50"
  },
  {
    "airlines": "SQ",
    "departure_airport": "CGK",
    "departure_time": "2021-08-17T17:00",
    "arival_airport": "SIN",
    "arival_time": "2021-08-17T19:30"
  },
  {
    "airlines": "QZ",
    "departure_airport": "CGK",
    "departure_time": "2021-08-17T10:05",
    "arival_airport": "DPS",
    "arival_time": "2021-08-17T12:20"
  },
  {
    "airlines": "GA",
    "departure_airport": "CGK",
    "departure_time": "2021-08-17T13:10",
    "arival_airport": "YIA",
    "arival_time": "2021-08-17T14:20"
  }
];

const renderTable = (data) => {
  let results = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let airlines = data[i].airlines;
    let departure_airport = data[i].departure_airport;
    let departure_time = moment(data[i].departure_time).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A')
    let arrival_airport = data[i].arival_airport;
    let arrival_time = moment(data[i].arival_time).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A')

    results += `<tr>
          <td>${airlines}</td>
          <td>${departure_airport}</td>
          <td>${departure_time}</td>
          <td>${arrival_airport}</td>
          <td>${arrival_time}</td>
        </tr>`;
  }
  document.querySelector("#flight tbody").innerHTML = results;
}

const filterFunction = () => {
  var input = document.querySelector('#filterInput');
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  if (filter.length == 0) {
    document.querySelector('#airlineButton').removeAttribute('disabled');
    document.querySelector('#timeButton').removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#airlineButton').setAttribute('disabled', true);
    document.querySelector('#timeButton').setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }
  var table = document.querySelector("#flight")
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      console.log(txtValue)
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
renderTable(flight_data);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: use a reduce function on the array, within the reduce, perform the time-comparison and return the sorted matches. If you run into a specific problem, update your question with your attempt (code) and describe the possible issue

Comment: _"Here is what it looks like..."_ - That information is not at all relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), you can have something like this

```
var time = moment('09:34:00', 'hh:mm:ss');
var startTime = moment('08:34:00', 'hh:mm:ss');
var endTime = moment('10:34:00', 'hh:mm:ss');

if (time.isBetween(startTime, endTime)) {
  console.log('is between')
} else {
  console.log('is not between')
}

// prints "is between"
```

Replace `time` with each flight's departure time.

Comment: Why should OP use momentjs?